# How to securely validate a user in a React App (using JWT tokens)

Tags: reactjs, security, jwt

I'm currently working on a React frontend, and I have a server running in Express. I have a login form that queries the server and receives a JWT authentication token if the username and password are valid.

I then grab that token, and set a `user` state.

```
try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username,
        password,
      });
      setUser(user);
```

Finally, I display the login form when the user is not logged in, and the content when the user is logged in.

```
 <div>
  {user ? (
    <div>
      <h2>blogs</h2>
      <p>{user.username} logged in </p>
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} />
      ))}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Login setUser={setUser} />
  )}
</div>
```

I was thinking about this process, and I was wondering — is this at all secure? We're basically performing user validation based on whether the `user` state is set. But since this is all in the front-end, can the user just go in and change the state of the `user` variable?

Comment: If the apis are secured with a jwt token, even if the user manages to change the state, he wont be able to get info or make post calls

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. So even if they're able to see the "logged in" state, they still won't be able to make any api calls if they're secured.

That makes sense — thanks!

Comment: Welcome, but storing jwt access tokens in localstorage will increase the security risks, till the token is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the token in Cookies (js-cookie can be used). If you need to authorize a path you can just check if the token exists in cookies. To make it more secure you need to add a security layer in backend APIs. While making request to a secure APIs you will first check if the token is valid and user is authorized or not. This can be done by adding middleware.